# How can I do this with one segue?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I want to pass movies's data to another controller also  pass another controller when progress is finished.Can I do this with one segue ?

```
class LoadingScreenViewController: UIViewController {

    var movies  = [Movie]()
    @IBOutlet weak var progress: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!

    override  func viewDidLoad() 
    {
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(LoadingScreenViewController.updateProgress), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        progress.setProgress(0, animated: true)
    }

    func updateProgress () {
        if progress.progress != 1 {
            self.progress.progress += 2 / 10

        } else {   
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {  () -> Void in

            })
            performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender:self)
            progress.hidden = true
            self.countLabel.hidden = true
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 
    {
        let controller : SearchViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SearchViewController
        if  segue.identifier == "segue"{
            controller.model = movies
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: please elaborate, what do you exactly mean by " also pass another controller when progress is finished" ?

Comment: What value or object you want to pass to `SearchViewController` ?

Comment: OK sorry about my language. If I use 2 segues my table view in SearchController updated 2 times. I want to this one time. I can't find pass data with perform segue or another solutions

Comment: I want to pass movies

Comment: But you are already passing movie object with this `if  segue.identifier == "segue"{
    controller.model = movies}`

Comment: also I want to pass  searchController  at the same time

Comment: So why not just add another line to prepareForSegue? Like `controller.controller = searchController`?

Comment: -because progress is finished here - 
    performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender:self)
  progress.hidden = true
        self.countLabel.hidden = true

    }

Comment: no need to pass searchController, just use extension as mentioned below. add the extension in any VC.

Answer (score 0):

Do following:-

```
 extension UIViewController {
        func addSearchController() {
          let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            self.view.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
        }


    }
```

Just call self.addSearchController() method in viewDidLoad method of required VC. No need to pass SearchController.